# What are the zero width elements in a regular expression?

Tags: regex

Recently, I have been seeing "zero width elements" in regular expressions.  What are they?  Can they be treated as ghost data, so that for replacement, they won't be replaced, and for `( )` matching, they won't go into the `matches[1]`, `matches[2]`, etc?

Is there a good tutorial for all its various uses?  Have they been here for a long time?  Which version of O'Reilly's Regular Expression book was the first to discuss them?

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same page, are you talking about assertions like the ones documented here? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w(v=VS.71).aspx

Comment: yes, and the `?!`, `?<!`, `?<=`

Comment: Well there's a lot of those. Is there something specific you're having trouble with? If not I'd suggest you check out the documentation on assertions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=VS.71).aspx and the link in my comment above - for .NET anyway). Are you working with .NET regular expressions or some other dialect?

Comment: O'Reilly has [several books on regex](https://ssearch.oreilly.com/?q=regular+expressions), but I assume you mean [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do) (currently in its 3rd edition, 2006) or else [Regular Expression Pocket Reference](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596514273.do) (currently in its 2nd edition, 2007).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The point of zero-width lookaround assertions is that they check if a certain regex can or cannot be matched looking forward or backwards from the current position, without actually adding them to the match. So, yes, they won't count towards the capturing groups, and yes, their matches won't be replaced (because they aren't matched in the first place).

However, you *can* have a capturing group inside a lookaround assertion that *will* go into `matches[1]` etc.

For example, in C#:

```
Regex.Replace("ab", "(a)(?=(b))", "$1$2");
```

will return `abb`.

A very good online tutorial about regular expressions in general can be found at http://www.regular-expressions.info (even though it's a little out of date in some areas).

It contains a specific section about [zero-width lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (and [Part II](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround2.html)).

And of course they are covered in-depth in both [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596528126/) and the [Regular Expressions Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520694/).

Comment: capturing groups inside zero-width regex are captured in many regex implementation including PCRE