# How to ban words with diacritics using a blacklist array and regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have an input of type text where I return true or false depending on a list of banned words. Everything works fine. My problem is that I don't know how to check against words with diacritics from the array:

```js
var bannedWords = ["bad", "mad", "testing", "băţ"];
var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + bannedWords.join("\\b|\\b") + '\\b', 'i');

$(function () {
  $("input").on("change", function () {
    var valid = !regex.test(this.value);
    alert(valid);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' name='word_to_check'>
```

Now on the word `băţ` it returns true instead of false for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [utf-8 word boundary regex in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881445/utf-8-word-boundary-regex-in-javascript)

Comment: That link does not help me. Or at least I don't understand how is helping me. Can you explain why do you think that my question is a duplicate of that?

Comment: Instead of using the word boundary `\b`, try using what  the referring answer suggested. And ăţ are not ASCII characters. That's why `\b` fails. This is where the utf-8 word steps in.

Comment: Simply put, diacritics means utf-8. That's why I flagged your question duplicated. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not sure of what the problem is. If you have a _list_ of banned words, put them into a single regex with alternations. Then check that. Why go through all this hassle? If you have a large list, make a regex trie out of a ternary tree. Grab this app (**[screenshot](http://www.regexformat.com/version_files/Rx5_ScrnSht01.jpg)**) to make it for you. And you shouldn't be using a word boundary anyway, you should use a whitespace boundary. `(?<!\S)(?:stuff|or|stuff)(?!\S)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chiu's comment is right: `'aaáaa'.match(/\b.+?\b/g)` yelds quite counter-intuitive `[ "aa", "á", "aa" ]`, because "word character" (`\w`) in JavaScript regular expressions is [just a shorthand for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word) `[A-Za-z0-9_]` ('case-insensitive-alpha-numeric-and-underscore'), so **word boundary** (`\b`) matches any place between chunk of alpha-numerics and any other character.  This makes extracting "Unicode words" quite hard.

For non-[unicase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicase) writing systems it is possible to identify "word character" by its dual nature: `ch.toUpperCase() != ch.toLowerCase()`, so your altered snippet could look like this:

```js
var bannedWords = ["bad", "mad", "testing", "băţ", "bať"];
var bannedWordsRegex = new RegExp('-' + bannedWords.join("-|-") + '-', 'i');

$(function() {
  $("input").on("input", function() {
    var invalid = bannedWordsRegex.test(dashPaddedWords(this.value));
    $('#log').html(invalid ? 'bad' : 'good');
  });
  $("input").trigger("input").focus();

  function dashPaddedWords(str) {
    return '-' + str.replace(/./g, wordCharOrDash) + '-';
  };

  function wordCharOrDash(ch) {
    return isWordChar(ch) ? ch : '-'
  };

  function isWordChar(ch) {
    return ch.toUpperCase() != ch.toLowerCase();
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' name='word_to_check' value="ba">
<p id="log"></p>
```

Comment: Your "just shorthand for" link displays backslashes but should not.  I assume this is a markdown error, but I'll let you correct it yourself.

Comment: `[\b]` and `[^\b]` don't work that way.  Because these are inside character classes, they are interpreted as "is a backspace character" and "is not a backspace character" ([read more here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html?selflavor=javascript "(select “JavaScript” as one of the languages)")).  The opposite of `\b` (zero-width word boundary) is `\B` (zero-width non-word boundary), which (in JavaScript) uses the same `[A-Za-z_0-9]` definition of "word characters" and is therefore unhelpful here.

Comment: Thanks for remarks: corrected link formatting. And thanks for that `/^[\b]$/.test('\u0008') === true` quip, I admit I didn't know that. But it was not that relevant, for I just wanted to demonstrate that "\b works just with ASCII" thing like you did in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see what's going on:

```js
alert("băţ".match(/\w\b/));
```

This is `[ "b" ]` because word boundary `\b` doesn't recognize word characters beyond [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). JavaScript's "word characters" are strictly `[0-9A-Z_a-z]`, so `aä`, `pπ`, and `zƶ` match `\w\b\W` since they contain a word character, a word boundary, and a non-word character.

I think the best you can do is something like this:

```js
var bound = '[^\\w\u00c0-\u02c1\u037f-\u0587\u1e00-\u1ffe]';
var regex = new RegExp('(?:^|' + bound + ')(?:'
                       + bannedWords.join('|')
                       + ')(?=' + bound + '|$)', 'i');
```

where `bound` is a reversed list of all ASCII word characters plus most Latin-esque letters, used with start/end of line markers to approximate an internationalized `\b`.  (The second of which is a [zero-width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280766/what-are-the-zero-width-elements-in-a-regular-expression) [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that better mimics `\b` and therefore works well with the `g` regex flag.)

Given `["bad", "mad", "testing", "băţ"]`, this becomes:

```js
/(?:^|[^\w\u00c0-\u02c1\u037f-\u0587\u1e00-\u1ffe])(?:bad|mad|testing|băţ)(?=[^\w\u00c0-\u02c1\u037f-\u0587\u1e00-\u1ffe]|$)/i
```

This doesn't need anything like `….join('\\b|\\b')…` because there are parentheses around the list (and that would create things like `\b(?:hey\b|\byou)\b`, which is akin to `\bhey\b\b|\b\byou\b`, including the nonsensical `\b\b` – which JavaScript interprets as merely `\b`).

You can also use `` var bound = '[\\s!-/:-@[-`{-~]' `` for a simpler ASCII-only list of acceptable non-word characters.  Be careful about that order! The dashes indicate ranges between characters.

Answer (score 2):

In stead of using word boundary, you could do it with

```
(?:[^\w\u0080-\u02af]+|^)
```

to check for start of word, and

```
(?=[^\w\u0080-\u02af]|$)
```

to check for the end of it.

The `[^\w\u0080-\u02af]` matches any characters **not** (`^`) being basic Latin word characters - `\w` - or the Unicode 1_Supplement, Extended-A, Extended-B and Extensions. This include some punctuation, but would get very long to match just letters. It may also have to be extended if other character sets have to be included. [See for example Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script_in_Unicode).

Since javascript doesn't support look-behinds, the start-of-word test consumes any before mentioned non-word characters, but I don't think that should be a problem. The important thing is that the end-of-word test doesn't.

Also, putting these test outside a non capturing group that alternates the words, makes it significantly more effective.

```js
var bannedWords = ["bad", "mad", "testing", "băţ", "båt", "süß"],
    regex = new RegExp('(?:[^\\w\\u00c0-\\u02af]+|^)(?:' + bannedWords.join("|") + ')(?=[^\\w\\u00c0-\\u02af]|$)', 'i');

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Banned = ' + regex.test(document.getElementById('word_to_check').value);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Enter word: <input type='text' id='word_to_check'>
<button onclick='myFunction()'>Test</button>

<p id='result'></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot to escape backslashes in string literals. Also this will let pass values like `bad!!1!` which I assume should be blocked.

Comment: Thanks @myf for pointing that out. I believe it's fixed now :)

Comment: better :] although now it bans values such as `băţăţ`, which I assume should be permitted.

Comment: @myf Think that's fixed now as well. :S

Comment: Yup, even better. Just  look after those `_bad_` underscores that leaked along with `\w` :]

Answer (score 2):

You need a Unicode aware word boundary. The easiest way is to use [*`XRegExp`*](http://xregexp.com/) package.

Although its `\b` is still ASCII based, there is a [**`\p{L}`**](http://xregexp.com/plugins/) (or a shorter `pL` version) construct that matches any Unicode letter from the BMP plane. To build a custom word boundary using this contruct is easy:

```
\b                     word            \b
  ---------------------------------------
 |                       |               |
([^\pL0-9_]|^)         word       (?=[^\pL0-9_]|$)
```

The leading word boundary can be represented with a (non)capturing group `([^\pL0-9_]|^)` that matches (and consumes) either a character other than a Unicode letter from the BMP plane, a digit and `_` or a start of the string before the `word`.

The trailing word boundary can be represented with a positive lookahead `(?=[^\pL0-9_]|$)` that requires a character other than a Unicode letter from the BMP plane, a digit and `_` or the end of string after the `word`.

See the snippet below that will detect `băţ` as a banned word, and `băţy` as an allowed word.

```js
var bannedWords = ["bad", "mad", "testing", "băţ"];
var regex = new XRegExp('(?:^|[^\\pL0-9_])(?:' + bannedWords.join("|") + ')(?=$|[^\\pL0-9_])', 'i');

$(function () {
  $("input").on("change", function () {
    var valid = !regex.test(this.value);
    //alert(valid);
    console.log("The word is", valid ? "allowed" : "banned");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/3.1.1/xregexp-all.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' name='word_to_check'>
```

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with characters outside my base set (which can show up at any time), I convert them to an appropriate base equivalent (8bit, 16bit, 32bit). before running any character matching over them.

```
var bannedWords = ["bad", "mad", "testing", "băţ"];
var bannedWordsBits = {};
bannedWords.forEach(function(word){
  bannedWordsBits[word] = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
    bannedWordsBits[word] += word.charCodeAt(i).toString(16) + "-";
  }
});
var bannedWordsJoin = []
var keys = Object.keys(bannedWordsBits);
keys.forEach(function(key){
  bannedWordsJoin.push(bannedWordsBits[key]);
});
var regex = new RegExp(bannedWordsJoin.join("|"), 'i');

function checkword(word) {
  var wordBits = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
    wordBits += word.charCodeAt(i).toString(16) + "-";
  }
  return !regex.test(wordBits);
};
```

The separator "-" is there to make sure that unique characters don't bleed together creating undesired matches.

Very useful as it brings all the characters down to a common base that everything can interact with.  And this can be re-encoded back to it's original without having to ship it in key/value pair.

For me the best thing about it is that I don't have to know all of the rules for all of the character sets that I might intersect with, because I can pull them all into a common playing field.

**As a side note:**

To speed things up, rather than passing the large regex statement that you probably have, which takes exponentially longer to pass with the length of the words that you're banning, I would pass each separate word in the sentence through the filter.  And break the filter up into length based segments. like;

1. checkword3Chars();
2. checkword4Chars();
3. checkword5chars();

who's functions you can generate systematically and even create on the fly as and when they become required.