# how to use regex with arabic text

Tags: java, regex, nlp

I'm trying to find the main stem of arabic word the user will enter لاعبون and the program will try to remove ون from the word, the remain part of the word will be لاعب and then try to find the main stem لعب in my list of stems, can i do that with regex or any advice. Thanks

Comment: regex gets applied on word and characters. make sure the language u are going to use regex on has UNICIDE/UTF-8 support. Then after that it will be regular string and regular regex. Nothing changes there because regex is locale independent

Comment: Java [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) supports a number of Unicode scripts, blocks and categories that you may leverage for this. I think the question's too broad as is. Try to add some code and expected output illustrating what you're trying to do.

Comment: You should be able to identify patterns using regex the same way as for English, as long as you are using the correct character encoding.

Comment: You might have some use of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24028429/515948) or, better yet, in the [documentation](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Categories)

Comment: @Hani It's a question with no research evidence or problem statement. It's a bad question.

Comment: @Hani you shouldn't upvote the question just because somebody else dislikes it.  Your votes should be based on your own opinions.  The fact that you don't understand why someone downvoted it doesn't make your half-hearted opinion more valid than their genuinely held one.

Comment: This is an extremely broad and complex question, and to answer it correctly requires knowledge of Arabic morphology as well as  regular expressions.  I don't think you'll get a good answer from the Stack Overflow community.  I've voted to close it as "too broad".

Answer (score 1):

Most regex engines these days, including Java's, support Unicode. For your particular case, you want something like this:

```
String text = "لاعبون";
text.replaceAll("\\u0648\\u0646", "");
```

Basically, all you need to do is replace every specific Unicode codepoint you want removed with the empty string. Done and done.

Comment: This is an oversimplification.  OP has a lot of text to deal with, and he only wants to remove `"ون "` when it occurs at the end of a word.  Also, this only attempts to answer half of his question.  He wants to extract the stem `"لعب "` from the remainder of the word.  For the latter, he can't just remove all alif characters, because some alifs are part of the stem and some are not.

Answer (score 0):

do you even need to use the encoded "code points"?  [this works](https://regex101.com/r/Cg1GbA/2):

regex: `ون(.*)`

replace: `$1`

Answer (score 0):

here is full example

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class regex {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*)" + "ون");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("لاعبون");
    Matcher m2 = p.matcher("يييي");
    System.out.println(m.matches());
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m2.matches());

}
```

}

will print

```
true
لاعب
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Since each glyf keeps the charcter codes there is no big difference comparing to English for example. you should just write down patterns to match 3 character roots and then write syntax to convert them to another pattern/template.

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're describing will have a large set of variables.  Do you know all the prefixes, suffixes, can you make a list of them?

If you can do both of the above, that gives you a list that you can then test your word against and remove characters as appropriate.

See a previous answer to a similar question ([How to ban words with diacritics using a blacklist array and regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39140488/how-to-ban-words-with-diacritics-using-a-blacklist-array-and-regex/39267709#39267709))

Convert your characters to a character representation in UTF-8 (I believe this will save you some trouble.)

Then using simple regex.

Lets say (because I can't convert these myself right now)  ون =  x021-x023

Your works (converted to 16 bit) pushed into regex and passed through this > s/^x021-x023//g

would trim the x021-x023 off your word.

Covert it back into your normal character set.

And you have your trimmed short word.